# Laravel 3 bundles in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

In L3 there was great thing - packages. They could have own routes and worked as plugins and made software more modular. How to achieve this in L4? I see packages little different from bundles.

Thank You!

Comment: You mean Bundles in L3? Why view them differently? They achieve the same thing across the two versions of the framework... they are just created using a different process, as should be expected.

Comment: I see them as components, for example, image upload and resize. But if I want to create admin section and my own project (only) modules, is it good to use packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundle is a specific packaging for Laravel 3, great to add easily a package but not a standard.

Laravel 4 is more modular because it accepts packages form all the php community. It uses a standard as package manager, [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/), and Laravel 4 is managed itself as a package.

You just have to create a composer.json file like this one :

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "1.4.*"
    }
}
```

And execute `composer update`. All the dependencies of your project will be installed in accordance with the versions you specify in this file. It's really the best pattern to manage a lot of libraries for a team.

Bundles and packages are really similar, the gift wrap and the shipping way change but that's all.

Comment: So It will be good practice if I make admin section and different modules for my project as packages?

Comment: We generally reserved the Composer managed packages for the external libraries. If you generalize a piece of code, for several projects in your enterprise or for the community, it is a good practice but if this code is just used by the application, it has to be placed in the /app folder and managed by your version control system.

Comment: I tried to place them in the app folder but then i am unable to add specific routes to every package

Comment: Yes, the same as comment above. And it will loose modularity, if mix with app/[modules]|[controllers]|[views] directory.

Comment: The benefit of Composer is that you're not exactly limited to those directories you've mentioned. You might like to make a `src` directory in your `app` directory, and in there have your `Admin` "package", so to speak. Making your admin a separate package isn't the best approach unless you're going to be dropping it in to other projects. You can define your routes for each section in different files. Don't think you have to use `routes.php` to define your routes, it's a lot more flexible than that. Just be sure to autoload everything in your `composer.json`.